# Postgres - how to displays data for the previous year?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have sql

```
select
    name,
    tanggal,
    status
from
    tbl_person
where
    status = 'PROSES'
    and date_part('year', tanggal) = 2021 - INTERVAL '1 YEAR'
```

tanggal is date 2021-01-01

I want to display previous year's data for example in 2020, how to write the correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your method:

```
where status = 'PROSES' and
      date_trunc('year', tanggal) = date_trunc('year', current_date) - interval '1 year'
```

However, I prefer to avoid functions on the column -- so the query is easier to optimize.  So I would recommend:

```
where status = 'PROSES' and
      tanggal < date_trunc('year', now()) and
      tanggal >= date_trunc('year', now()) - interval '1 year'
```

This just uses `now()` rather than `current_date` because it is easier to type.